# Unable to use the overridden BackColor property of a UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, .net-3.5, gdi

### Scenario

I am using a **UserControl** for creating a customized control.

I am trying to **override the BackColor** property of the UserControl, so that, on **BackColor** property change of the UserControl, the BackColor of the control doesn't gets changed and the value is stored in the variable named **BackColor_Value**:

Here is the code for it:

```
Color BackColor_Value = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.ActiveCaption);
[Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
[Bindable(true)]
//[AmbientValue(false)]
//[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "ActiveCaption")]
public override Color BackColor
{
      get
      {
          return BackColor_Value;
      }
      set
      {
          BackColor_Value = value;
      }
 }
```

**Note:** The BackColor is just stored in a variable but not used anywhere.
[image]

**EDIT**: What I'm trying to accomplish is to change the BackColor of a selection of controls when the UserControl's BackColor property is set, leaving the UserControl's background Color unchanged.

### Problem

For some reason the Backcolor of the control is getting changed according to the variable **BackColor_Value** I have specified.

- Why is the default functionality still happening even after I have overridden the property?
- What attribute should I use to stop this from happening?

### Complete Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MaterialUI_Control
{
    public partial class MaterialPanel : UserControl
    {
        public MaterialPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Color BackColor_Value = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.ActiveCaption);
        [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        [Bindable(true)]
        [AmbientValue(false)]
        [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "ActiveCaption")]
        public override Color BackColor
        {
            get
            {
                return BackColor_Value;
            }
            set
            {
                BackColor_Value = value;
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set `return Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.ActiveCaption);` in the property getter. i.e., don't return `BackColor_Value`.

Comment: Otherwise, use `public new Color BackColor`, set `base.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.ActiveCaption);` in the constructor, remove `this.Refresh();` in the property setter (since you don't actually change anything).

Comment: `BackColor` property will be used by `OnPaintBackground` method to render the control. If you want to use the `BackColor` property for another purpose, you need to override `OnPaintBackground` to not rely on `BackColor`. Or you can shadow/hide the property `public new Color BackColor { get; set; }`. But in general, to me, it looks like an XY problem. What's the read problem that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`BackColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property will be used by [`OnPaintBackground`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onpaintbackground?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method to render the control. If you want to use the `BackColor` property for another purpose, you can use either of the following options:

- Override `OnPaintBackground` and paint the background yourself (ignore the `BackColor`)
- Shadow/hide the `BackColor` property

You also need to consider another fact about the `BackColor` property, it's an [ambient property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8#remarks), which means if you don't set it explicitly, it will follow the value of the parent control's `BackColor` property.

**Example 1 - Override `OnPaintBackground` and paint the background yourself**

You can override the `OnPaintBackground` method and ignore the value of `BackColor` property:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var method = typeof(Control).GetMethod("PaintBackground",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic,
        null,
        new Type[] { typeof(PaintEventArgs), typeof(Rectangle), typeof(Color) },
        null);

    //Paint with a default constant back color, here for example Color.Red
    method.Invoke(this, new object[] { e, ClientRectangle, Color.Red });
}
```

In this case, changing the back color will not change the rendering of your control, however it will change the `BackColor` of the child controls which doesn't explicitly have a `BackColor` assigned.

**Example 2 - Shadow/hide the `BackColor` property**

You can shadow/hide the `BackColor` property:

```
public new Color BackColor { get; set; }
```

In this case, changing the back color will not change the rendering of your control, it also have no impact on the child controls and if you want to change back color of child controls, you need to add some logic in setter of the property.

Also to set the color which is used by `OnPaintBackground`, in the constructor, you can set `base.BackColor = Color.Blue;` or something.

Comment: Cool! No problem :) However make sure it's not an XY problem ;)

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The thing i was doing was, on UserControl backcolor change, i wanted to change selective controls with the back color that has been specified.

Comment: So I guess overriding the `OnPaintBackground` makes more sense as the solution. Because the child controls will automatically follow the `BackColor` which you set for the parent, also we used a fixed back color for the parent.

Comment: You can probably just set `base.BackColor = [The predefined Color]; base.OnPaintBackground(e);` in `OnPaintBackground`. It has the same side effect (the Color Name alone would change in the PropertyGrid), that should be corrected. But, as you said, it looks like a *curious* way to solve the problem. If one wants to override this property behavior, to only return a predefined Color, no matter what has been set in the Designer, you might as well remove the Property and set the `base` value in the constructor.

Comment: @Jimi I'm not sure it's the best way to approach the problem, but regarding to the OP comment above, I think the OP wants to have `BackColor` property in the property grid, and when they use it to set the back color to something, instead of redrawing using the specified back color, just use it to set the back color of some of child controls. It probably means the container should have a fixed back color. However I can imagine some other solutions as well.

Comment: This is nowhere described in the question. I'll edit it, base on a comment the OP left here. There should be a custom property for this: `public Color BackColorOfAllChildControlsNotTheContainers {get; set; }` :)

Comment: @Jimi The thing is, `BackColor` of child controls will follow the back color of parent control because of being ambient property. So if you add new property, then you need some logic to stop child controls from following back color of the parent control and force them to follow the new property. That's why I didn't add a new property, instead, I used the same `BackColor` property and just override `OnPaintBackground` to ignore the back color. This way, when you change `BackColor` property of the parent, back color of children will change, but the parent will be rendered with a constant color.

Comment: Yes, I edited the question describing what is the intended behavior. I mentioned a custom Property, because overriding the default behavior defeats (in a way) the *Principle of Least Astonishment* :) A custom property can be used to get this effect, anyway (I don't know how you got the OP's intentions in the first place. Did you borrow Hans Passant's crystal ball? :)

Comment: haha :D Just tried to show how can stop rendering the background based on the `BackColor` property that you see in property grid. I thought it may be useful for some cases.